# Post a comment on a Pinterest Pin with PHP

Tags: php, pinterest

I'm working on a script that search pins from the provided keyword and comments on it.

I'm using this [Pinterest PHP Bot](https://github.com/seregazhuk/php-pinterest-bot) by [Sergey Zhuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6816329/sergey-zhuk) for this purpose. This is the method that the developer has shared in the documentation but it doesn't seem to work for me.

`$result = $bot->pins->comment($pinId, 'your comment');`

But the searching part is working really well.

The developer asked to use the login method if I want to perform tasks like creating pins, commenting etc. Which I have used as well but in vain.

Has someone used this script and can guide me if I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my library. I've just tested and it works fine. Check if you use the latest version. 
Try to test comments with my test pin:

`var_dump($bot->pins->comment('462393086724905917', 'test'));`

What is the output?

Then check if there are any errors, after you leave a comment:

`var_dump($bot->getLastError());`

It seems that you have used wrong ids.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sergey :) I'm getting this output: `bool(true)` and no errors.

Comment: I was trying to test comment on my own pin **298574650279368125** but it doesn't work. I'm using it like this: `$bot->pins->comment($pinId, 'your comment')` and adding the pin ID as integer. But in your answer you have used a sting. But when I used my pin ID as string it worked...

Comment: Oh, I see! Yes, I will change source code to accept integers also and convert them to strings.

Comment: It wasn't a data type issue. I've checked it, it accepts both strings and integers.

Comment: Yeah I was using the wrong pin IDs... Thanks for your cooperation :)

Comment: @SergeyZhuk - I'm curious, does your scripting allow people to use the OAuth Token to connect to their Pinterest Account and add a comment, or does it have to use their email/password? I'm looking for a way to post comments only on a pin using a pin id - while using the oauth details and not a user's email/pass credentials. Please let me know.

Comment: No, my library emulates a browser behavior, so it requires password/login to work. Maybe for your needs, you should use official Pinterest API.